# Get Wages Yearly Increment Column Wise Using Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I've a requirement to get employee yearly wages increment column wise and before I get into, please see the below sample first:

Sample 1:   1 - 4 years increment

```
EmpID   EmpName 1st Increment   2nd Increment   3rd Increment   4th Increment
1       John    1000            2000            3000            4000
2       Jack    2000            4000            8000            16000
```

Sample 2:   5 - 8 years increment

```
EmpID   EmpName 1st Increment   2nd Increment   3rd Increment   4th Increment
1       John    5000            6000            7000            8000
2       Jack    32000           64000           128000          256000
```

I guess, I am able to make understand what's it actually. The columns 1 - 4 increments should be kept static and for 1 - 4 years increment, the 1st sample could be managed and I've tried a query but not that efficient: (The idea is to get the 1st, 2nd , 3rd, 4th rows of a specific id 1 for sample 1)

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EmpID ASC) as RowNum
    FROM EmpIncrement 
    WHERE EmpID = 1
)
SELECT 
    CTE.EmpID AS ID, CTE.Amt AS Amount,
    (CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 1 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '1st Increment',
    (CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 2 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '2nd Increment'
FROM 
    CTE 
WHERE 
    CTE.RowNum IN (1, 2)
```

This is what I've got:

[image: sample_increment]

In sample 2, when it comes to 5th increment, then the increment amount should be placed in the '**1st Increment**' column and the rest accordingly. There could be a good solution but can't get it done. Could be it done with an easy approach or any idea/sample would be appreciated. Thanks.

The table structures and sample are as follows (Script):

```
USE [Demo]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employee]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [NAME] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [ADDRESS] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [SALARY] [float] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK__Employee__3214EC2714270015] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ON

INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [NAME], [ADDRESS], [SALARY]) 
VALUES (1, N'John', N'Germany', 12000)
INSERT [dbo].[Employee] ([ID], [NAME], [ADDRESS], [SALARY]) 
VALUES (2, N'Jack', N'France', 14000)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[Employee] OFF


SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmpIncrement]
(
    [IncrementID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EmpID] [int] NULL,
    [Amt] [float] NULL,
    [IncrementDate] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_EmpIncrement] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IncrementID] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EmpIncrement] ON

INSERT [dbo].[EmpIncrement] ([IncrementID], [EmpID], [Amt], [IncrementDate]) 
VALUES (1, 1, 2000, CAST(0x0000A6D800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[EmpIncrement] ([IncrementID], [EmpID], [Amt], [IncrementDate]) 
VALUES (2, 2, 8000, CAST(0x0000A6D800000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[EmpIncrement] ([IncrementID], [EmpID], [Amt], [IncrementDate]) 
VALUES (3, 1, 1000, CAST(0x0000A56A00000000 AS DateTime))
INSERT [dbo].[EmpIncrement] ([IncrementID], [EmpID], [Amt], [IncrementDate]) 
VALUES (4, 2, 4000, CAST(0x0000A56A00000000 AS DateTime))

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[EmpIncrement] OFF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works.

```
WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT e.ID,e.[Name],ei.Amt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,IncrementDate)) as RowNum
    FROM EmpIncrement ei 
         JOIN Employee e ON ei.EmpID = e.ID
),

CTE2 AS
    (
    SELECT CTE.ID 'Id',CTE.[NAME] 'Name',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 1 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '1stIncrement',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 2 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '2ndIncrement',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 3 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '3rdIncrement',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 4 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '4thIncrement',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 5 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '5thIncrement',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 6 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '6thIncrement',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 7 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '7thIncrement',
    SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 8 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '8thIncrement'
    FROM CTE 
    GROUP BY CTE.ID,CTE.[NAME]
    )

SELECT ID,[NAME], 
       CASE WHEN [5thIncrement] > 0 THEN [5thIncrement] ELSE [1stIncrement] END AS '1st Increment',
       CASE WHEN [6thIncrement] > 0 THEN [6thIncrement] ELSE [2ndIncrement] END AS '2nd Increment',
       CASE WHEN [7thIncrement] > 0 THEN [7thIncrement] ELSE [3rdIncrement] END AS '3rd Increment',
       CASE WHEN [8thIncrement] > 0 THEN [8thIncrement] ELSE [4thIncrement] END AS '4th Increment'
FROM CTE2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jason and worked perfectly. I would like to know two things - I understood what you have tried to do in `CTE` and `CTE2`. In the `SELECT` query (Third section), what have you done actually? Though I got to know a little, just trying to clarify. Another thing is: could it be made dynamic like on the 10th increment, column name '**10th Increment**' and so on for an employee?

Comment: The 3rd section that is selecting from CTE2 is checking to see if there is a 5th,6th,7th, or 8th increment. If the amount is greater than 0, then the logic will be true and therefore use that value. If the value is 0, then the lower increment values will be used. If you and increments to the `EmpIncrement` table, then you would need to add another line of code to CTE2 and the 3rd part. You could copy and paste and modify the values. You wouldn't need to do anything to the first part.

Comment: Also, you could comment out the last part, the CTE2 syntax, and run the query to see the difference. This should show you exactly what the 3rd part is doing.

Comment: Then in the **CTE2** part, this should be written: `SUM(CASE WHEN CTE.RowNum = 10 THEN CTE.Amt ELSE 0 END) AS '10thIncrement'` and in the 3rd section, `CASE WHEN [10thIncrement] > 0 THEN [10thIncrement] END AS '10th Increment'`?

Comment: I would put an `ELSE` in the `CASE` statement. `CASE WHEN [10thIncrement] > 0 THEN [10thIncrement] ELSE NULL END AS '10th Increment'`