# Instead of ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server-2000

In my last post (Below link), I've tried to use the `ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY` and finally got the required solution. See the following link:

[Get Wages Yearly Increment Column Wise Using Sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44099373/get-wages-yearly-increment-column-wise-using-sql)

Now I am trying to use the following query in Sql server 2000, just for demonstration purpose. I know, `ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY` can't be used in it. And after some googling, tried to use the following for Sql server 2000: (1st query)

```
SELECT k.ID, k.[Name], m.Amt,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EmpIncrement l WHERE l.EmpID <= m.EmpID) as RowNum
    FROM EmpIncrement m
JOIN Employee k ON m.EmpID = k.ID
```

And I got this output:

```
ID  Name    Amt     RowNum
1   John    2000    2
2   Jack    8000    4
1   John    1000    2
2   Jack    4000    4
```

Similarly when I use the following with `ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY`, then it shows different output: (2nd query)

```
SELECT k.ID, k.Name, m.Amt, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EmpID ORDER BY DATEPART(yy,IncrementDate)) as RowNum
    FROM EmpIncrement m 
JOIN Employee k ON k.ID = m.EmpID
```

Output:

```
ID  Name    Amt     RowNum
1   John    1000    1
2   John    2000    2
1   Jack    4000    1
2   Jack    8000    2
```

So it's noticed that the grouping for the employee ids (**RowNum**) are different in both the queries where the output of the second query is correct. I would like to know the difference of both the queries output and if the 1st query is equivalent to `ROW_NUMBER ORDER BY`. Thanks.

**Note:** I didn't include the table structure and sample data here again. Never mind - You can see the earlier post for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recreate the `partition by EmpId`, your subquery should have `l.EmpId = m.Empid`. You really need a unique column or set of columns to unique identify a row for this version to work properly. In an attempt based on the given data, if `EmpId, Amt` are a unique pair you can use `and l.Amt < m.Amt`. If you have a surrogate`id` on the table, that would be better instead of `Amt`.

```
select
    k.id
  , k.[Name]
  , m.Amt
  , ( select count(*)
      from EmpIncrement l
      where l.Empid = m.Empid
        and l.Amt <= m.Amt
  ) as RowNum
from EmpIncrement m
  inner join Employee k
    on m.Empid = k.id
```

If you have no set of columns to uniquely identify and order the rows, you can use a temporary table with an `identity()` column.

```
create table #temp (tmpid int identity(1,1) not null, id int, [Name] varchar(32), Amt int);
insert into #temp (id, [Name], Amt);
select
    k.id
  , k.[Name]
  , m.Amt
from EmpIncrement m
  inner join Employee k
    on m.Empid = k.id;

select 
    t.id
  , t.[Name]
  , t.Amt   
  , ( select count(*)
          from #Temp i
          where i.Empid = t.Empid
            and i.tmpId <= t.tmpId
      ) as RowNum
from #temp t
```

Comment: I guess, with the word `Generic`, you are asking about unique id in the table and if so, it's included. Thanks for the answer @SqlZim.

Comment: @AT-2017 I should have used the word `surrogate`, I'll correct that.

Comment: It worked and I just slightly changed this section `where l.Empid = m.Empid and l.Amt <= m.Amt` to this `where l.Empid = m.Empid and l.IncrementID >= m.IncrementID` (In the 1st query) as I've unique id in the **EmpIncrement** table. Thanks a lot @SqlZim.